# Start service automatically when windows start

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I install a service in windows server 2008 r2 , and want to start it when windows start

```
 class Program : ServiceBase
{
    ...    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new Program());
    }

    public Program()
    {
        this.ServiceName = "ABPS";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);

        this.start();//a method that start works
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should [add installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf(v=vs.110).aspx) to your application.

> To determine how your service will be started, click the
> ServiceInstaller component and set the StartType property to the
> appropriate value.
>
> - Manual The service must be manually
>   started after installation.
> - Automatic The service will start by itself whenever the
>   computer reboots.
> - Disabled The service cannot be started.

you can start your service in `AfterInstall` event handler

```
void ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
    using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller.ServiceName))
    {
         sc.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an installer to your Service application, where you will need to set the StartType property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

```
serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
```