# .NET start app automatically when Windows starts

Tags: c#, .net

I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456460/start-service-automatically-when-windows-start).

This is my code

```
private void RegisterInStartup(bool isChecked)
{
    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
    if (isChecked)
    {
        registryKey.SetValue("CTIPopupForIPPhone", Application.ExecutablePath);
    }
    else
    {
        registryKey.DeleteValue("CTIPopupForIPPhone");
    }
}
```

In the constructor of the form I've added this:

```
RegisterInStartup(true);
```

But when I restart Windows, the app doesn't start automatically. What have I missed?

Comment: if you have 64-bit windows, you may try `Software\Wow6432Node\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Comment: @ieaglle okay, i will try that, which means i have to restart my windows to test your solution, i will be back to you in 10 minutes

Comment: @ieaglle i don't have `Windows` entry under `Wow6432Node` in the registry, are you sure your path is correct ?

Comment: @ieaglle i changed it now to `SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run` but now the app is not even running, though the registry path is correct. help please

Comment: after you run your code is there `CTIPopupForIPPhone` key with correct executable path in this registry path?